# Wireshark's time column only displays zeroes. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: wireshark, packet-sniffers

Im using wireshark and the time column doesn't show captured time,
only zeroes.

Any ideas? What can I do to make time column shows correct value?

Thanks!

I tried to change some settings in view-time display format , but is still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Edit -> Preferences -> Columns -> [+] -> Title: AbsTime, Type: Absolute Time -> OK`?  (Personally, I use the `"Absolute date, as YYYY-MM-DD, and time"` type.)

See also the [Wireshark User's Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html/#ChWorkTimeFormatsSection).